# Something causes my phone to hang and reboot

Tags: reboot, logging

This problem always happens after I restore my apps from Titanium Backup and move them to the SD card, regardless which ROM. However, I noticed that this problem has something to do with the SD card. Since the logcat is too long, I posted it here:

- Logcat #1: http://pastebin.com/5qAEz3n7
- Logcat #2: http://pastebin.com/Hd7uXPrc
- Logcat #3: http://pastebin.com/Xc6evYsM
- Logcat #4: http://pastebin.com/yQFuXdTu

P.S. all these logcats occured during the same session, after that, the phone started becoming slow, hanging, then rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't think this is related to the SD card per se. Some applications just don't handle being placed on SD or being back-upped and restored with Titanium Backup too well. I've experienced trouble with restored apps myself and solved the problems with removing the app and installing a fresh copy from the Market.

Comment: Can you mention a few apps? I've never experienced anything like this.

Comment: In your logcat there is an Exception that appears to be related to some sort music application: `E/DatabaseUtils( 3297): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: album_artist: , while compiling: SELECT _id, album, artist, composer, date_added, duration, mime_type, _size, title, track, year, album_id, album_artist FROM audio WHERE ((is_music=1 OR is_podcast=1)  AND (date_added >=?  OR date_modified >=?  )) ORDER BY date_added`

So my bet is that it is a music player. Did you restore the default music player with Titanium Backup by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you restored system app data from a different ROM?

```
I/ActivityManager( 3000): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:LocationFriendService for broadcast [..] pid=5275 [..]
W/dalvikvm( 5275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5275): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:            static:
```

Similar error quoted in above comments by Paul. This usually happens when you restore system databases from one ROM to another, where the database structur may be different. Apps in this case often force-close, things become laggy.

**IMPORTANT:** If you want to restore system data to a different ROM with Titanium Backup,

1. be **VERY** careful
2. best only do so for one app/database at a time (to be sure it went OK)
3. use TB's *migration* feature (that's an option to be explicitly turned on -- it takes care e.g. not to overwrite databases, but migrate the data into the existing ones)
4. optional, but often helpful: in the configs troubleshooting section, enforce the systems SQLite engine to be used.
5. repeat from 1. only if you are sure everything did fine!